# Splitting a string in an indian language (non-english) to get each character

Tags: javascript, node.js

If the string is in english, the following works:

```js
"string".split('') // returns ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

But what if the string is in some other language like hindi? `.split('')` will not work because:

```js
"कमाल".split('') // returns ["क", "म", "ा", "ल"]
```

whereas I am interested in getting `["क", "मा", "ल"]`.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [grapheme-splitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapheme-splitter) module

```
const GraphemeSplitter = require('grapheme-splitter')
const splitter = new GraphemeSplitter()
let graphemes = splitter.splitGraphemes("कमाल");
console.log(graphemes);
```